# How to maintain index when splitting sentences into words and reapplying sentiment polarity to each word?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, nlp, textblob

I have a dataframe of sentences that looks like this:

```
             text
0  this is great!
1  how dare you?!
```

I can succesfully use `TextBlob.words` (https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#tokenization) to break each sentence into its individual words.

An example would be

```
a = TextBlob('moon is big')
print(a)

WordList(['moon','is','big'])
```

`WordList` creates  a list type `blob.Wordlist` that saves each word.

I can break the sentences in the dataframe into individual words and save it it in a variable using this code:

```
for i in df.text:
    d = TextBlob(i)
    words_list=d.words
```

To get the sentiment of every word, I need to reapply TextBlob to every word. I can do this with the below code and append the polarity score in a list.

```
lst=[]
for i in text.text:
    d = TextBlob(i)
    words_list=d.words
    for i in words_list:
        f = TextBlob(i)
        print(f.sentiment)
        lst.append(f.sentiment.polarity)
```

At this point, I dont know which polarity score belongs to which sentence, because my goal is that I want to average the polarity score of every word per row of dataframe and generate a new column `score`. Is there anyway I can pass an index per `blob.Wordlist` so I can match the average back to the dataframe?

code so far:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd
import statistics as s

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['this is great!','how dare you?!']})

lst=[]
for i in text.text:
    d = TextBlob(i)
    words_list=d.words
    for i in words_list:
        f = TextBlob(i)
        print(f.sentiment)
        lst.append(f.sentiment.polarity)
        for i in lst:
            z = s.mean(lst)
            df['score'] = z
```

New df should look like this:

```
             text     score
0  this is great!  0.2
1  how dare you?!  0.3
```

NOT

```
             text     score
0  this is great!  0.133333
1  how dare you?!  0.133333
```

Thank you in advance.

edit:

@kevin here is your code with the proper df names

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd
import statistics as s

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['this is great!','how dare you?!']})
df['score'] = 0

for j in range(len(df.text)):
    lst=[]
    i = df.text[j]
    d = TextBlob(i)
    words_list=d.words
    for i in words_list:
        f = TextBlob(i)
        print(f.sentiment)
        lst.append(f.sentiment.polarity)
    z = s.mean(lst)
    df['score'][j] = z
```

Comment: you need to clear the list in between rows

Comment: @DJK thank you for the response, I am not following what you mean could you show me please?

Comment: are you sure you mean calculations are correct? I get something 2.7 and 0...

Comment: That is what I hope to get in the dataframe but I keep getting 0 and 0 for `score`

Comment: If you only rewrote your code `lst=[] ... lst.append(f.sentiment.polarity)` as a function `def polarity_score(sentence):`, that would be better. Your `lst[]` would be reinitialized on each sentence.

Comment: @smci that is a great idea, thank you very much.

Comment: A tip to make your code more readable: `for i in text.text: ...  for i in words_list: ... for i in lst: ...` Don't call every loop variable `i`, give them distinct meaningful names. In this case: `for sentence in text.text: ...  for word in words_list: ...` and the final loop `for i in lst:` seems unnecessary, just compute the mean sentiment of that sentence once after the `for word in words_list: ...` loop has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy option here, just use pandas built in to solve this. First strip special characters. Then, convert each word to a column. Next apply `TextBlob` to each word and extract the polarity from the blob. Lastly take the mean of each row

```
df['Socre'] = df.text.str.replace(r"[^\w\s]+","").str.split(" ",expand=True)\
              .applymap(lambda x: TextBlob(x).sentiment.polarity).mean(1)
```

---

**Edit** - The above solution will only work for equal length sentences, use this for a general case

```
import numpy as np

df['Score'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: np.mean(
              [TextBlob(r[0]).sentiment.polarity for r in TextBlob(x).ngrams(1)]))
```

Comment: this is beautiful and works really well. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you might want something more like this?
For each sentence, you get the mean of the word-sentiments, and then put that value in the DF.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd
import statistics as s

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['this is great!','how dare you?!']})
df['score'] = 0

for j in range(len(text.text)):
    lst=[]
    i = text.text[j]
    d = TextBlob(i)
    words_list=d.words
    for i in words_list:
        f = TextBlob(i)
        print(f.sentiment)
        lst.append(f.sentiment.polarity)
    z = s.mean(lst)
    df['score'][j] = z
```

Comment: thank you for the response. Your understanding is correct, for each sentence, I want to take the average of every word. However your code is giving me score zero for both rows, when `this is great!` should have a score of `0.26666666666666666` (0.8/3)

Comment: does it print anything?

Comment: It does print the data frame with the score column, yes

Comment: hm, ok.  try this

Comment: Kevin, still same issue.

Comment: Kevin, i think the issue is that is that once the first set of scores have been calculated the lst is clearing itself and taking the score of the last

Comment: Kevin, another thing I noticed is that `j` is only taking into consideration index `1` and not anything else.

Comment: Kevin, the issue is for sure, that the index is starts at 0 to 1 not 1 to 2, so I am not sure how to take the actual index numbers and apply that in `j`

Comment: well, what is text.text?

Comment: Kevin, text.text was the orginial df and column with data(I know bad name). I made an edit with your code, with different name